# Messages app crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, messages

I can't open Messages app on my iPhone 5S with iOS 8.3 (no jailbreak) - it crashes on start. I suspect a malformed message caused this, so I want to delete all messages from all senders to see if it helps.

I tired allowing iOS to delete messages older than 30 days, but it didn't help - the bad message is recent, and I can't afford waiting a month to be able to use SMS again. I also don't have any older backups I could restore.

Is there any way I can delete all messages without opening the app itself? Or some other way this problem could be fixed?

Comment: iMessage bug may be. Apple fix : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204897

Comment: @PratikaRana This helped! Could you re-post it as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the recent iMessage bug. Here is the fix Apple has provided on its website. Hope it helps.

[support.apple.com/HT204897](http://support.apple.com/HT204897)